# Can't require coffee-script in the node

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, nvm

I have installed `coffeescript` and `node` via `nvm`. But I'm getting errors when I require the coffee in Node.js console:

```
var cs = require('coffee-script/register');
// => Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script/register'
```

or

```
var cs = require('coffee-script');
// => Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script'
```

My environment:

```
node -v
// => v5.0.0

coffee -v
// => CoffeeScript version 1.10.0

npm list -g coffee-script
// => ~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib
// => └── coffee-script@1.10.0
```

I think this problem is causing other errors like this:

```
knex --help
// => Failed to load external module coffee-script/register,coffee-script
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't install `coffee-script` locally, `npm i coffee-script --save` in your project's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

This work for me

Answer (score 0):

The registered module name is `coffee`; just do `var cs = require('coffee');`